# Netbeans 7.3.1 broken

Tags: java, ubuntu, netbeans, ide

As you can see on this screenshot:

[image: Netbeans]

- Some buttons on this window are missing
- The "Please wait..." text does not change change and nothing is loaded
- I can close the window but I can never create a project
- I tried to re-install and delete all Netbeans related stuff but the problem remains

It seems related to a Java VM problem but Eclipse and PhpStorm are working without problem.

My Java version:

```
java version "1.6.0_27"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.6) (6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu0.10.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

My system is **Ubuntu 10.04 LTS**.

Comment: And are you getting any error messages when running from the command line (or in `.xsession-errors`)?

Comment: No error. Netbeans 7.3.1 didn't work at all and 7.2 was totally unstable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the [installation instructions](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/73/install.html#requiredsoftware) you need the JDK7 if you want to use any of the Java features.

Comment: I reinstalled the full package and it finally work, http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-7-netbeans-download-432126.html, but I had the same problem with Netbeans 7.2 before. Thanks.